# My test class keep failing. Moving the rev scheduler with the close date

Tags: apex, class

Im not getting any coverage with this test class. YOu'll see the trigger and the class handler are here.

==============================================================

```
@isTest
private class OpportunityReSchedulingTest {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        // TO DO: implement unit test
        Test.starttest();

            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.Name='NewAcc';
            insert acc;

            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
            opp.Name='NewOpp';
            opp.AccountId=acc.Id;

            opp.StageName='Prospecting';
            opp.CloseDate=Date.today().addDays(10);

            insert opp;

            Product2 Prod =  new Product2();
            Prod.Name='NewProd';
            Prod.IsActive=True;
            insert Prod;

            PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
            pbe.Product2Id=Prod.Id;
            pbe.IsActive=True;
            pbe.UnitPrice=70;
            pbe.Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
            pbe.UseStandardPrice=false;

            insert pbe;

            OpportunityLineItem opli = new OpportunityLineItem();
            opli.UnitPrice = 57;
            opli.Quantity = 12;
            opli.OpportunityId=opp.Id;
            opli.PricebookEntryId=pbe.id;
            insert opli;

            opp.CloseDate = opp.CloseDate.addDays(20);
            update opp;


        Test.stoptest();
    }
}
```

=========================================================================

```
public with sharing class OpportunitySchedulingHandler {

     //Update LineItemSchedule dates for all scheduling dates

    public static void ScheduleDateUpdate(String oppid, Integer DayDiff) 
    {
       List<OpportunityLineItem> idval = [SELECT id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId=:oppid];
       List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> datelist = new List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>();
       for (Integer i = 0; i < idval.size(); i++)
       {
           datelist = [SELECT ScheduleDate FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule WHERE OpportunityLineItemId =:idval[i].id];
           Date firstDate = datelist[0].ScheduleDate.addDays(DayDiff);
           datelist[0].ScheduleDate = firstDate;

           Integer day = firstDate.day();
           Integer month = firstDate.month();
           Integer year = firstDate.year();

           for (Integer k = 1; k < datelist.size(); k++)
           {
               Integer nYear = year;
               Integer nMonth = month + k;
               Integer nDay = day;

               if (nMonth > 12) {
                   nMonth = nMonth - 12;
                   nYear = nYear + 1;
               }

               Set<Integer> longMonths = new Set<Integer> {1,3,5,7,8,10,12};

               if (nDay == 31 && ! longMonths.contains(nMonth)) {
                   nDay = 30;
               }

               if (nDay > 28 && nMonth == 2) {
                   nDay = 28;
               }

               Date mydate = date.newInstance(nYear,nMonth,nDay);
               datelist[k].ScheduleDate = mydate;
           }
           if(!datelist.isEmpty())
           {
                update datelist;
           }
        }
    }    

      //Update ServiceDate with closeDate

    public static void ScheduleServiceDateUpdate(String oppid)
    {
        List<Opportunity> oliList = [SELECT Id, Name, CloseDate, (SELECT Id, ServiceDate, OpportunityId from OpportunityLineItems) from Opportunity where Id =:oppid];
        List<OpportunityLineItem> oliUpdateList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
        for(Opportunity x : oliList)
        {
            for(OpportunityLineItem oli : x.OpportunityLineItems)
            {
                oli.ServiceDate = x.CloseDate;
                oliUpdateList.add(oli);
            }
        }
        if(!oliUpdateList.isEmpty()) 
        {
            update oliUpdateList;
        }
    }
}
```

==========================================================================

```
trigger OpportunityReScheduling on Opportunity (after update, before update, after insert) 
    {
        for (Opportunity o: Trigger.new)
        {
            if (Trigger.isBefore)
            {
                Opportunity oldCloseDate = Trigger.oldMap.get(o.ID);
                if (o.CloseDate != oldCloseDate.CloseDate) 
                {
                    Integer Oldday = Integer.valueOf(oldCloseDate.CloseDate.Day()); 

                    Integer day = Integer.valueOf(o.CloseDate.Day());
                    Integer month = Integer.valueOf(o.CloseDate.Month());
                    Integer year = Integer.valueOf(o.CloseDate.Year());                 

                    Integer DayDiff = day - Oldday;

                    OpportunitySchedulingHandler.ScheduleDateUpdate(o.id, day, month, year, DayDiff);
                }
            }

            if (Trigger.isAfter || Trigger.isInsert)
            {
                OpportunitySchedulingHandler.ScheduleServiceDateUpdate(o.id);   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Scott, could you please update your post with the verbatim error text and which line it takes place on? A little description of your code and test strategy will also help - it's a lot of code to just wade through to find an issue.

Comment: Sure. Of course.

Comment: ystem.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 006q000000Gf3z7AAB; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, OpportunityReScheduling: execution of BeforeUpdate

caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Class.OpportunitySchedulingHandler.ScheduleDateUpdate: line 12, column 1
Trigger.OpportunityReScheduling: line 12, column 1: []

Comment: The above error happens when I run the test class

Comment: Just by looking at your code and counting lines, I think line no. 12 in `OpportunityReScheduling` is this line `Date firstDate = datelist[0].ScheduleDate.addDays(DayDiff);` and it seems that your `dateList` never had any records returned from the line above, thus causing this failure.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.   I tried to expand the test class by adding this code. OpportunityLineItemSchedule oplisk= new OpportunityLineItemSchedule();
           oplisk.ScheduleDate=opp.CloseDate.addDays(20);
           oplisk.OpportunityLineItemId=opli.Id;
          
            insert oplisk;

Comment: Thanks for all your help.   I tried to expand the test class by adding this code. OpportunityLineItemSchedule oplisk= new OpportunityLineItemSchedule();
           oplisk.ScheduleDate=opp.CloseDate.addDays(20);
           oplisk.OpportunityLineItemId=opli.Id;
          
            insert oplisk;     When I reran the test class, I got an error saying the following. System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Type]: [Type] .

Answer (score 0):

You have an unguarded list reference in your handler class:

```
   datelist = [SELECT ScheduleDate FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule WHERE OpportunityLineItemId =:idval[i].id];
   Date firstDate = datelist[0].ScheduleDate.addDays(DayDiff);
```

`dateList` is empty in your test context. You need to

- Define the appropriate schedules in your test class.
- Add assertions to your test class to demonstrate that the behavior of your code is correct.
- Add logic to your handler class to provide a logic path for the situation when no line item schedules are present, rather than throwing an exception.
- Refactor and bulkify your code. You are running one SOQL query per Opportunity, and then one SOQL query per Opportunity Line Item. This will quickly result in limits issues if your code executes across multiple Opportunities in the same transaction. Trailhead has good information about bulkifying trigger code, and you can find lots of questions on that subject here on SFSE.

Comment: Code it up to 70% covered, add the follwoing ......OpportunityLineItemSchedule oplisk=new OpportunityLineItemSchedule();
              
              oplisk.ScheduleDate=system.today();
              oplisk.Type='Revenue';     Keep getting the error 
              oplisk.OpportunityLineItemId=opli.Id;
              oplisk.Revenue=200;
              insert oplisk;

Comment: ..keep getting the error System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: Type, Quantity, unknown (invalid quantity/revenue for given type): [Type, Quantity, unknown]

Comment: I figured it out !!!!!!! Thanks. I actually READ the error. Problem was I was not designating the correct format for the type I was choosing. Thanks again for your hep. Got up to 92% coverage!!

Comment: Hey Scott, glad you figured it out. Just for your reference, the format on SFSE encourages unitary, specific questions that can be solved in the scope of one answer - comment chains do not work well for follow-ups. You're always welcome to open new questions for further issues you're not able to work out!